# 3 div dynamic arrangement with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have 3 `divs` in a row which stacks in the order `red`, `green`, `blue` on `xs` devices.

On `md` devices, however, I want `blue` to be placed right below `red` which does not happen if the height of `red` surpasses `green`.

This is the layout:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="red col-md-6">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div class="green col-md-6">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div class="blue col-md-6">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

If i place `blue` in a separate `row` that would just cause unwanted space after `red` when height of `green` is greater than height of `red`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This : http://jsfiddle.net/U4Yer/

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 no-padd">
     <div class="red">content 1</div>
     <div class="blue">content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="green col-md-6 col-xs-6 no-padd">
    Content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.green { background: green; height:200px; } 
.no-padd { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: This compromises the ordering of `div`s on `xs` devices.

Comment: you can change the class name col-xs-6 to col-xs-12. also add the another one class for small devices "col-sm-6.